# Install Gitlab Runner on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I just connected my GKE cluster to my gitlab project but I can't find the Gitab Runner integration, see image below

[image: Available Integrations image]

So how can I add gitlab runner ? and it will be using this connection with cluster ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked the official guide :
[Gitlab CI/CD on GKE](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/03/27/gitlab-ci-on-google-kubernetes-engine/)
That will help you hit the ground running and point the right direction.
Also leave a comment below if you found something else.

Comment: Yes that's what I did, and I got stuck on Step 6, I can't find any application

Comment: That guide is outdated

Comment: @halfpastfour.am In what way?

Comment: GitLab CI/CD on kubernetes no longer works with "applications" that you can configure in the GUI. Instead, you have to setup the helm chart yourself on kubernetes and manage all desired applications yourself using configs. Right now you would have to install an agent on your cluster yourself, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/index.html.